# Multi-level subquery with JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: jpa

I have the following JPA entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name="application_user")
public class ApplicationUser {
    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private String userid;

    @Column(name="last_write_time")
    private Instant lastWrite;

    //other fields omitted
}

@Entity
@Table(name="demographic")
public class Demographic {
    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private String userid;

    //primary key is a foreign key link
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
    private ApplicationUser user;

    //other fields omitted
}
```

My goal is to retrieve all of the Demographics that contains users where the last write time is the max value in the column. I pretty much want to write the following SQL using the JPA CriteriaBUilder

```
select * from demographic where
  userid in (
    select userid from application_user where
      last_write in (
        select max(last_write) from application_user
      )
  )
```

I tried writing the following CriteriaBuilder Code to accomplish this goal and it compiles successfully. Note I am using the generated Metamodel classes.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Demographic> c = cb.createQuery(Demographic.class);
Root<Demographic> root = c.from(Demographic.class);
root.fetch(Demographic_.user, JoinType.INNER);

Subquery<Instant> sqLatestUsers = c.subquery(Instant.class);
Root<ApplicationUser> subRootLatestUsers = sqLatestUsers.from(ApplicationUser.class);
sqLatestUsers.select(cb.greatest(subRootLatestUsers.<Instant>get(ApplicationUser_.LAST_WRITE)));
Predicate predicateLatestUsers = subRootLatestUsers.get(ApplicationUser_.LAST_WRITE).in(sqLatestUsers);

Subquery<ApplicationUser> sq = c.subquery(ApplicationUser.class);
Root<Demographic> subRoot = sq.from(Demographic.class);
sq.select(subRoot.<ApplicationUser>get(Demographic_.USER)).where(predicateLatestUsers);
Predicate containsUsers = subRoot.get(Demographic_.USER).in(sq);

c.select(root).where(containsUsers);
```

The code compiles and successfully deploys in Wildfly 14, but when I execute the code, the get the following error (with white space to improve readability):

```
Invalid path: 'generatedAlias2.user' :  Invalid path: 'generatedAlias2.user'
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias2.user' [
select generatedAlias0 from com.company.model.Demographic as generatedAlias0 
  inner join fetch generatedAlias0.user as generatedAlias1 
    where generatedAlias2.user in (
      select generatedAlias2.user from com.company.model.Demographic as generatedAlias2 where generatedAlias3.lastWrite in (
        select max(generatedAlias3.lastWrite) from com.company.model.StarfishUser as generatedAlias3
      )
    )
]
```

Is chaining subqueries (nested subqueries) allowed by the JPA spec? Did I find something that is syntactically correctly but not actually allowed?

Comment: what if you just take out the `root.fetch(Demographic_.user, JoinType.INNER);` That join doesn't seem to be in your original query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out how to get the subquery to work. First is my updated Utility method

```
public static <R, T> Subquery<T> getLatestSubelement(CriteriaBuilder cb, CriteriaQuery<R> c, Class<T> clazz, SingularAttribute<T, Instant> attribute) {
    //Get latest timestamp
    Subquery<Instant> sq = c.subquery(Instant.class);
    Root<T> subRoot = sq.from(clazz);
    sq.select(cb.greatest(subRoot.<Instant>get(attribute)));

    //Get object with the latest timestamp
    Subquery<T> sq2 = c.subquery(clazz);
    Root<T> subRoot2 = sq2.from(clazz);
    sq2.where(subRoot2.get(attribute).in(sq));
    return sq2;
}
```

Here is the code that uses the utility method

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Demographic> c = cb.createQuery(Demographic.class);
Root<Demographic> root = c.from(Demographic.class);
joinType = JoinType.INNER;
//use fetch instead of join to prevent duplicates in Lists
root.fetch(Demographic_.user, joinType);

Subquery<ApplicationUser> sq = JpaUtil.getLatestSubelement(cb, c, ApplicationUser.class, ApplicationUser_.lastWrite);
c.where(root.get(Demographic_.user).in(sq));
TypedQuery<Demographic> q = em.createQuery(c);
Stream<Demographic> stream = q.getResultStream();
```